# Meteor remove blaze template in autorun

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

I have a loading template. need to load `loading template` whenever client subscribe data from the server.

```
Template.myTemplate.onCreated(function() {
    var loading;
    Template.instance().autorun(function() {
         if (!Template.instance().subscriptionsReady()) {
           loading = Blaze.render(Template.loading, document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]);
         } else {
           Blaze.remove(loading);
         }
    });
});
```

1st time `Blaze.render` and `Blaze.remove` works fine. But again if i do more subscription, It keep on adding `loading` template. How do I remove template from the DOM when else part executes?

Comment: I would simply check whether the template has already been rendered or not. Then again I don't understand your issue. What do you mean  "remove right template"? You only render and remove `loading` template here...

Comment: @durrrr whenever the subscription ready  is `true` Blaze add `loading template` element in body tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!Template.instance().subscriptionsReady()) {
    if (Template.loading.isRendered) {
        return;
    }
    // if not rendered to DOM, then do render
} else {
    Blaze.remove(loading);
}
```